# Davies-Meyer without XORing in the previous state

Tags: compression-function

A Davies-Meyer ccompression function operates with $H_{i} = E(m_{i}, H_{i-1}) \oplus H_{i-1}$. Why not use $H_{i} = E(m_{i}, H_{i-1})$ instead?

Comment: Opens up meet-in-the-middle requiring double the state size.

Comment: Just think about how you invert this function... You only need the meet in the middle if you have a specific message padding that you have to match and a fixed IV

Comment: Related (but unfortunately no answer) [Complexity to find an preimage of a hash function](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20255/complexity-to-find-an-preimage-of-a-hash-function)

Comment: @CodesInChaos: now [Complexity to find an preimage of a hash function](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20255/555) is answered.